# Regex non-Word boundary and spaces

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a single regex that will match any sentence that contains a "new" word then "ee" non-word boundary in it. Below is the code where anything I put before or after non-word boundary returns False.

```
String sa = "this is new freeCode ";
System.out.println(sa.matches(".*\\s\\bnew\\b\\sfre.*")); //True
System.out.println(sa.matches(".*\\s\\Bee\\B\\s.*"));     //False
System.out.println(sa.matches(".*\\Bee\\B.*"));           //True
```

Comment: Excuse me, what is the question? Why you get `True`, `False`, `True`?

Comment: first regex matching word boundary with spaces which gives me True and i am fine with that, in second case non word boundary is not working with spaces so i can not construct a regex which will match a string which have "new" word boundary and then "ee" non-word boundary in it.

Comment: try this .*new.*free[^ ]

Comment: Could you please provide sample valid and invalid input? I feel you are looking for something like `".*\\snew\\s.*\\Bee\\B.*"`. You do not need `\b` in `\snew\s` since between `\s` and `n` there is a word boundary. It is just redundant there.

Comment: "this is new freeCode" --valid string    "this is new old but freeCode" --invalid  string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the explanation why these tests yield these results:

> `System.out.println(sa.matches(".*\\s\\bnew\\b\\sfre.*")); //True`

`this is new freeCode` contains `something`+`whitespace`+`word boundary` + `new` + `word boundary` + `whitespace`+`fre`+`something`. Word boundary matches inbetween `n` and `w f`.

> `System.out.println(sa.matches(".*\\s\\Bee\\B\\s.*"));     //False`

Non-word boundary `\B` between `\s` and `e` cannot match since `e` is a word character. Thus, no match.

> `System.out.println(sa.matches(".*\\Bee\\B.*"));           //True`

Non-word boundary `\B` matches between `e` since `e` in `freecode` is in not at a word boundary position (it is between 2 letters, word characters), and the final `e` is followed again by a letter (`c` in this case). This is a valid match.

To enable both checks, you need to combine the first and third regex patterns. You do not need both `\s\b` and `\b\s`. If you want to just match a whole word `new` remove `\s`:

```
System.out.println(sa.matches(".*\\bnew\\b.*\\Bee\\B.*"));
```

If you need to match spaces around `new`, use:

```
System.out.println(sa.matches(".*\\snew\\s.*\\Bee\\B.*"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^.*?\\bnew\\s\\S*\\Bee\\B.*$
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cK4iV0/19

This will match the word `new` and then `ee` without `word boundary` on either side.